# How many levels do the games on the VTech Kidizoom Camera Pix have?

Tags: vtech-kidizoom-camera-pix

For Christmas this past year, a small member of my household received the gift of a **VTech Kidizoom® Camera Pix<sup>TM</sup>**. It did not take any of us long to discover that this comes loaded with several games:

- Bunny Jump
- Train Track Stack
- Where's the UFO?
- Worm Maze

We quickly started leveling up. But where does it all end? We have not beaten any of the games yet, and are wondering exactly how much of a time commitment these require.

**Exactly how many levels do each of these games have?**

Nothing is mentioned about any of this in the [product manual](https://www.vtechkids.com/assets/data/products/%7BD2D60D44-98D0-4094-81B9-BA19298247BA%7D/manuals/193600_KidizoomCameraPixManual_02.23.16(2016)_FINAL.pdf).
The only version information I can find on the software is "VTech 1936".

[image: VTech 1936]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is, after many months of occasional, and somewhat lackadaisical play, we finally leveled-up to the end of each game.

#### Bunny Jump

- 3 levels (carrot, radish, rutabaga)
- 3 stages per level
- Level-up after completion of all 3 stages
- Progress is only saved after completion of all 3 stages

[image]

#### Train Track Stack

- 3 levels (cat, monkey, bunny)
- 3 stages per level
- Level-up after completion of all 3 stages
- Progress is only saved after completion of all 3 stages

[image]

#### Where's the UFO

- 3 levels (cloudy, rainy, tornadoes)
- 3 stages per level
- Level-up after completion of all 3 stages
- Progress is only saved after completion of all 3 stages

[image]

#### Worm Maze

- 20 levels
- Level-up after each level
- Progress is saved after completion of each level

[image]

> [image]

---

In retrospect, most adults could probably sit down and finish most of these in one sitting
*(except for Worm Maze... that was actually kinda hard)*